# How to hover on SVG element and changes polygon element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have made this image using SVG. Here is the fiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/9y723z5c/1/
```

Now you can see an open box with the text **Decide Value**. This is the hover effect I want. By default all box is close but I want to open each box like the **Decide Value** box when I hover over on it.

**Open box SVG code is below:**

```
<g id="Group-10">
    <text x="400" y="200" fill="red" style="font-size : 20px; width : 500px;">Decide Value</text>
    <polygon id="Stroke-14" fill="#FF4691" points="472.301332 231.804779 501.852722 214.74142 531.404111 231.803671 501.857151 248.86703"></polygon>
    <polygon id="Stroke-15" fill="#FC1874" points="543.406769 243.803228 543.406769 277.926624 513.854272 294.988875 513.855379 260.866587"></polygon>
    <polygon id="Stroke-16" fill="#B81154" points="472.299671 255.803228 472.359465 289.998598 501.85549 306.99109 501.85549 272.867694"></polygon>
</g>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how can I do this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Draw all boxes as closed.
2. Give each group containing the boxes a `class="box"`. Give each polygon a appropriate class `top`, `left` and `right`.
3. Move the group with the background inside the related `.box` group.
4. Define a CSS `transform` property for each polygon on `:hover` over the group.
5. Set `pointer-events: all` for the `.box` group. That way, the hover effect will be triggered as soon as the pointer is over the background.
6. Optionally, define a `transition` between states.

```css
.box {
    pointer-events: all;
}
.box > polygon {
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.background {
    opacity: 0.1;
    fill: #ff056a;
}
.box .top {
    fill: #ff4691;
}
.box:hover .top {
    transform: translate(0, -12px);
}
.box .right {
    fill: #fc1874;
}
.box:hover .right {
    transform: translate(10.4px, 6px);
}
.box .left {
    fill: #b81154;
}
.box:hover .left {
    transform: translate(-10.4px, 6px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" height="150px" width="150px">
  <g class="box">
    <g class="background">
      <polygon points="105.233,43.9505 60.2853,18 15.3382,43.9505 15.3382,95.8503 60.2853,121.801 105.233,95.8503" />
      <polygon points="120.027,35.4088 60.2853,0.916406 0.543312,35.4088 0.543312,104.392 60.2853,138.884 120.027,104.392" />
    </g>
    <polygon class="top" points="89.838,52.836 60.286,69.9 30.73,52.838 60.282,35.774" />
    <polygon class="right" points="60.285,104.022 60.286,69.9 89.838,52.836 89.838,86.96" />
    <polygon class="left" points="30.79,87.031 30.73,52.838 60.286,69.9 60.285,104.022" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just Supper Dupper :) Wow, but is that background can be bright smoothly and again back to less bright? I mean the light ping color background.

Comment: Change the opacity value on hover: `.box:hover .background { opacity: 1; }`. Again, defining a transition is possible.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score -4):

There are very good libraries for this, but you're gonna have to put some effort into learning them (just a little bit, really). The library is called [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/), The other one isn't really a library, it's a plugin to further ease the use of the library, the plugin is [snap-animation-states](https://bkdiehl.github.io/). It makes animating SVG's **with** the library extremely easy. Their API is really simple and powerful. I've used it to create the effect of the dropdown-hamburger-menu turning to a cross back and forth in a matter of minutes.